# Two Views, one appears sometimes and when so, the other one takes it space

Tags: ios, uistoryboard

I have an image and a label who are are next to each other inside a TableCell (among other elements). Sometimes the image has to be shown, and sometimes not.

What I want is that the label takes all space when the image has to be hidden, and respects its space (so it does not appear over the image) when it has to be shown.

In Android I would not have a problem doing it; I would put those two elements in a LinearLayout and I would mark the image´s visibility as GONE when I have to hide it, and then the text would start naturally where the image should be. But with the storyboard I am a bit lost and I do not know how to control this wanted behaviour. Is there a similar technique as the one that I mentioned for Android? I have to achieve it without AutoLayout.

I tried to change the origin of the frame of the label when the image is there, but it got all weird when the table downloads new elements:

```
- (void)displayImage
{
self.image.hidden = !_question.showImage;

    // Make a bit extra space for the image
    if(_question.showImage){
        CGRect labelFrame = [self.unreadLabel frame];
        labelFrame.origin.x = labelFrame.origin.x +20;
        [self.unreadLabel setFrame:labelFrame];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I was not taking into account that the cells are recycled and that I had to set them up also when the text has to take all space.

The resulting method would look like this:

```
- (void)displayImage
{
    self.image.hidden = !_question.image;

    // Make a bit extra space for the image
    CGRect labelFrame = [self.unreadLabel frame];
    CGRect imageFrame = [self.image frame];
    if(_question.showimage){
        labelFrame.origin.x = imageFrame.origin.x + imageFrame.size.width + 3;
        [self.unreadLabel setFrame:labelFrame];
    } else{
        labelFrame.origin.x = imageFrame.origin.x ;
        [self.unreadLabel setFrame:labelFrame];
    }
}
```